# Are Force.com Platform limits, per org or per name space?

Tags: governorlimits, isv, namespace

Within the Salesforce Governor Limits [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), there are many limits that operate at a platform or org level as opposed to at a transaction level. I understand the detail and working of these, but wanted clarification from anyone with real world experiences or that has performed specific testing around these.

For some transaction level it is stated that a name-spaced app gets its own allowance.

And for some org level limits it is stated that an app gets its own limits (e.g. custom tabs).

But there are some that it seems should have some level of name-space allowance but this is not stated in the spec. Some examples below, but the question is not about these specific limits:

- Custom settings cache limit of 10mb per org - Suggests that if an app is installed into an org that has reached this limit already, the app may not function.
- Maximum 5 batch jobs queued or active - If an org is already maxed on this, installing an app that relies on batch apex may not function correctly.

> So I guess the question really is: *Has anyone performed any testing
>   or have any real world examples that identify anomalies in the spec
>   around this matter and what were the findings.

Comment: I have revised this question to make the query clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Salesforce doesn't care who's apps an Org is running or under what namespace they run when they're consuming API calls. All SF cares about is how much of their allocated API resources that are available to it that an Org is consuming. They don't charge an ISV for the use of those resources/API calls, they charge the Org who's running the ISV's application.

In essence, everyone has to "play nice" and learn to share the resources that are available so they don't take down the servers. If an Org needs more API calls they have to pay for them, so SF can allocate them to that Org. That's because if SF does that, they're not available for another org to use as SF would expect in their resource sharing model. Either that or the Org will need to find a way to make more efficient use of the resources/API calls available to them by using different apps or different methods.

You might say that's something of an incentive to ISV's to also make the best use of API calls in their apps. Resource hungry apps aren't going to be a good choice for Orgs to use if they're hogging their API calls unnecessarily. This is particularly noted at the bottom of the Help Page on [API Usage Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_api_rate_limiting.htm).

**Edit**

Further research has yielded the following from Developer.Salesforce.com on [Per-transaction Apex Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm):

> Certified managed packages, that is, **managed packages that have passed the security review for AppExchange, get their own set of limits for per-transaction limits with the exception of some limits.** Certified managed packages are developed by Salesforce ISV Partners, are installed in your organization from Force.com AppExchange, and have unique namespaces.
>
> Here is an example that illustrates the separate certified managed package limits for DML statements. If you install a certified managed package, all the Apex code in that package gets its own 150 DML statements, in addition to the 150 DML statements your organization’s native code can execute. This means more than 150 DML statements might execute during a single transaction if code from the managed package and your native organization both execute. Similarly, the certified managed package gets its own 100 SOQL queries limit for synchronous Apex, in addition to the organization’s native code limit of 100 SOQL queries, and so on.

Additionally, from the [Salesforce Quick Limits Guide](https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf):

> Push Notification Limits
>   The maximum number of push notifications that are allowed for each mobile application associated with your Salesforce organization
>   depends on the type of application.
>
> - Maximum number of push notifications allowed for Limit: 
>     50,000 notifications per app per
>     day
> - Mobile applications provided by Salesforce (for example, Salesforce1): 
>     35,000 notifications per app per
>     day
> - Mobile applications developed by your organization for internal employee usage: 
>     5,000 notifications per app per
>     day
>     Mobile applications installed from the AppExchange

From the above, its clear that certified managed packages do indeed receive additional limits with respect to at least some APIs. If there's more than this, I'd recommend you check in the SF ISV Partner Documentation to find it.

Comment: Thanks very much, I guess I understand the principles. I am really looking for anyone who has done testing or actual examples. My question is not limited to any specific limit (perhaps I should not have referenced specifics) but those that generally operate at a platform level. There are some anomalies I feel between the spec and what would be polite and there are some areas where it is stated that managed apps have separate limits, but other areas where it would seem appropriate. So really looking for folks that have come up against these anomalies. I will review the question and update.

Comment: I agree this information is useful but it doesn't answer the question.  I came across this question while debugging a batch process that sometimes hits the limits.  In the debug log the cumulative usage list separated by namespace.  So if  "Number of SOQL queries: 40 out of 200" for one namespace do the other namespaces share the same 200 or do they each get 200.

Comment: As I understood the documentation, for SOQL, the managed package would get 100 and the Org would get it's normal limits on top of that for completing the execution of the transaction once the managed package had used all of it's additional limits granted to it by SF; meaning the transaction gets the benefit of the limits available from both namespaces.